# Copying multiple files inside a Google Cloud bucket to different directories based on file name

Tags: google-cloud-platform, copy, google-cloud-storage, bucket, gsutil

Suppose I have multiple files in different sub-directories with names like `20060630 AD8,11 +1015.WAV` and `20050508_Natoa_Enc1_AD5AK_1.WAV`. Now I know that all these files will have a substring like `AD` (in the first file) and `AD`, `AK` (in the second). There are total 16 of these classes (`AD`, `AK`, `AN` etc) that I've made as  empty folders in the top level directory.

I want to copy all these files according to the substrings matched into their respective directory. Now using `gsutil`, the commands may come like:

```
gsutil cp gs://bucket/Field/2005/20060630 AD8,11 +1015.WAV gs://bucket/AD/20060630 AD8,11 +1015.WAV
```

How can this approach work for automating the task for thousands of files in the same bucket?

Is it safe to assume an approach like:

```
if 'AD' in filename:
    gsutil cp gs://bucket/<filename> gs://bucket/AD/<filename>
elif 'AK' in filename:
    gsutil cp gs://bucket/<filename> gs://bucket/AK/<filename>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write an easy BASH script for this. The code would be pretty simple since [gsutil supports wildcards](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames) and it can recursively dive into sub-directories to find your files.

```
#!/bin/bash

bucket_name=my-example-bucket
substring_list=(
  AD
  AK
  AN
)

for substring in "${substring_list[@]}"; do
   gsutil cp gs://$bucket_name/**/*$substring* gs://$bucket_name/$substring/
done
```

I also see that you have some Python experience, so you could alternatively leverage the [Python Client for Google Cloud Storage](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/tree/master/storage) along with a similar wildcard strategy.

Comment: Is there no authentication required, since I'll be running this on Google Colab? Also, your link has a missing 'e'.

Comment: I don't know bash that well, but won't that code be throwing all the files in the top level directory rather than in the matched substring folders?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the link typo. It's been fixed.
That code will copy each file to its matching sub-directory at the root level of the bucket.
And I'm not familiar with Google Colab, but whatever environment you run the code in will have to be authenticated to your GCP account in order to do anything there.